# Antiderivative of $f\cdot (f')^a$ for $a\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

Let $f$ be a $C^1$ function with $f'>0$, and let $a\not= 0$ be a real number.
Is there a closed form for the integral
$$ \int f(x) f'(x)^a \mathrm dx? $$

Certainly if $a=1$, then the integral is simply $f^2/2 + c$, but I do not see a way of doing it for arbitrary $a$

Comment: As a note, the “good twin” $f^af’$ has an easy antiderivative, but I guess your question originates from that

Comment: @b00nheT Thanks for the comment. Actually these integrals appeared somewhat randomly in a project I am working on, and it would be nice to have a closed form for them, but I guess this might not be possible =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no closed form for that.  Indeed, try this one $f(x) = x\log x$, $a=1/2$:
$$
\int x \log x \sqrt{1+\log x}\;dx
$$

---

New example with $f$ defined on all of $\mathbb R$ and $f'>0$.  Take $f(x) = x+e^x, a=1/2$.
$$
\int(x+e^x)\sqrt{1+e^x}\;dx
$$

Comment: Nice example, thanks. I am also assuming that $f$ is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$ and satisfies $f'>0$ for all reals (I was a bit unclear with this in the post), but I suppose that there might not be a closed form even assuming that.